# Most complete tool for developing on Glassfish 4

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, plugins, glassfish

Just wanted to ask for recommendations on the most complete tool for developing on Glassfish 4.
I know there is an Eclipse plugin and a seemingly more complete Glassfish Tools Bundle (distributed as OEPE), but not sure what exactly one can do with each.

I should probably add at this point that I am a beginner with EE.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are beginning Java EE, I recommend that you download the Java EE 7 SDK[1], which includes the Java EE 7 Tutorial, samples, API documentation, etc. You can develop along with the Java EE 7 tutorial using NetBeans 7.4 [2] since the tutorial uses NetBeans to help you along. IMHO, that is a good place to start.

[1] http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html
[2] http://www.netbeans.org